# BIRT multiple sub-groups

Tags: report, birt

I've a question about birt multi level grouping. I have a dataset that returns the following:

```
    +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
    | Column0 | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 |
    +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
    | Data00  | Data11  | Data21  | Data    | Data    | Data    |
    +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
    | Data00  | Data11  | Data21  | Data    | Data    | Data    |
    +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
    | Data00  | Data11  | Data22  | Data    | Data    | Data    |
    +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
    | Data00  | Data11  | Data22  | Data    | Data    | Data    |
    +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
    | Data00  | Data12  | Data23  | Data    | Data    | Data    |
    +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
    | Data00  | Data12  | Data23  | Data    | Data    | Data    |
    +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
    | Data00  | Data12  | Data23  | Data    | Data    | Data    |
    +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
    | Data00  | Data12  | Data23  | Data    | Data    | Data    |
    +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Now i need to create a report with multilevel grouping that will give a result as shown below:

```
    +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
    | Column0 | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 |
    +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
    | Data00  | Data11  | Data21  | Data    | Data    | Data    |
    +         +         +         +---------+---------+---------+
    |         |         |         | Data    | Data    | Data    |
    +         +         +---------+---------+---------+---------+
    |         |         | Data22  | Data    | Data    | Data    |
    +         +         +         +---------+---------+---------+
    |         |         |         | Data    | Data    | Data    |
    +         +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
    |         | Data12  | Data23  | Data    | Data    | Data    |
    +         +         +         +---------+---------+---------+
    |         |         |         | Data    | Data    | Data    |
    +         +         +         +---------+---------+---------+
    |         |         |         | Data    | Data    | Data    |
    +         +         +         +---------+---------+---------+
    |         |         |         | Data    | Data    | Data    |
    +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I've already tried "Drop" and "Suppress duplicates". As well as deleting the group headers makes impossible cells dropping. The report generates data as shown below with empty cells on group headers:

```
    +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+
    | Column0 | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 | Explanation                            |
    +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+
    | Data00  |         |         |         |         |         | <--Empty cells of group header Data00  |
    +         +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+
    |         | Data11  |         |         |         |         | <--Empty cells of group header Data11  |
    +         +         +---------+---------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+
    |         |         | Data21  |         |         |         | <--Empty cells of group header Data21  |
    +         +         +         +---------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+
    |         |         |         | Data    | Data    | Data    |                                        |
    +         +         +         +---------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+
    |         |         |         | Data    | Data    | Data    |                                        |
    +         +         +         +---------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+
    |         |         |         | Data    | Data    | Data    |                                        |
    +         +         +         +---------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+
    |         |         |         | Data    | Data    | Data    |                                                |
    +         +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+
    |         | Data12  |         |         |         |         | <--Empty cells of group header Data12  |
    +         +         +---------+---------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+
    |         |         | Data23  |         |         |         | <--Empty cells of group header Data23  |
    +         +         +         +---------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+
    ...
    ...
    ...etc
```

Is it possible to group data with dropping cells like in the second table above?

Comment: Where did you try the drop? you should click on the Data00 CELL (not the data), be sure that you selected the CELL (check in the outline). Then go in the properties -> Advanced -> Drop and select ALL.  This will print cells like the second table. You must do this for each CELLS (Data11,Data21, Data12 and Data23 too)

Comment: Thank you for your response, Fanny V. Yes, i tried exactly what you say, but i get these empty cells as in the third table. My question - is there any solution without empty cells (as in the second table)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Apply Grouping for column0 to column2 and then remove all rows except group header and keep the group header drop property as detail.
2. For column3 in data cell insert table with 1 row 1 column.
3. Inside that table insert group.
4. In group on expression give all columns upto column3 with "and condition".Group on expression for column3 like **row["column0"]&&row["column1"]&&row["column2"]&&row["column3"]**.
5. In Table of contents give **row["column0"]**
6. Follow the above steps for column4 and column5. delete other rows in table except group header and keep the drop property of the group header of column3 to column5 as none.